# Error message "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" when I use udphdr

Tags: c

I write a programme with `udphdr.h`. And here is my header file list:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
```

And here is my code:

```
void dealUDPH(struct updhr* udph){
        if(udph==NULL){
            printk("udph is NULL!!\n");
        }else{
            printk("updh is %u\n",udph);
            printk("udp sport is %u\n",udph->source);
        }
}

static unsigned int hookfunc(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff **skb,
    const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out,
    int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)){
        struct iphdr *iph=ip_hdr(skb);
        struct ethhdr * ethh = eth_hdr(skb);
        struct tcphdr *tcph=tcp_hdr(skb);
        struct udphdr *udph=udp_hdr(skb);
        printk("*********************************************************\n");
        dealIPH(iph);
        dealETHH(ethh);
        dealTCPH(tcph);
        dealUDPH(udph);
        printk("*********************************************************\n");
        return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
mymodule-objs:=main.c
obj-m += main.o

else
PWD := $(shell pwd)
KVER := $(shell uname -r)
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(KVER)/build

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.mod.c *.ko *.symvers *order *.markers *-
endif
```

When I compile the file, it says the line: `printk("udp sport is %u\n",udph->source);` is error, and the error information is `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`.

What is the matter? How do I solve it?

Comment: I think it's a typo in `void dealUDPH(struct updhr* udph){`. `struct updhr` probably should be `struct udphdr`.

Comment: @FredLarson I correct it and complie again, it still doesn't work

Comment: I think you got Jonathan's typo. See his comment on his answer.

Comment: Once you have asked the question and gotten answers, don't go modifying the question content to invalidate the answers, even if the problem was primarily a typo.  Either annotate the correction in place, or simply leave alone.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK,I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
struct updhr* udph
```

You probably mean:

```
struct udphdr* udph
```

(In the context of: `void dealUDPH(struct updhr* udph){`.)

Note that as long as you don't need to reference any members in the structure, or allocate a copy of the structure, you can use `struct anyNameYouLike *ptr` as a parameter without much further ado.  However, if the name appears for the first time in a function prototype (declaration or definition), you should get warnings like:

```
$ gcc -g -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror -c xx.c
xx.c:2:23: error: ‘struct xyz’ declared inside parameter list [-Werror]
 void something(struct xyz *ptr)
                       ^
xx.c:2:23: error: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [-Werror]
xx.c:2:6: error: no previous prototype for ‘something’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
 void something(struct xyz *ptr)
      ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
rmk: error code 1
$
```

The 'no previous prototype' message is accurate and a consequence of using the `-Wmissing-prototypes` option (in conjunction with `-Werror`).

#### `xx.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void something(struct xyz *ptr)
{
  if (ptr == 0)
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I missed a `d` in the replacement first time - `udphdr` rather than `udphr`.